# send message to all friends on facebook and twitter

Tags: facebook, ios4, twitter

I want to send a pre-defined message to all friends on Facebook and twitter. Once the user log in. I will pass username and password. And I know i have to use different apis for both Facebook and twitter.
  But I don't know which apis to be used and how to implement this functionality. Please explain as I am new to objective C.

Comment: Please make your question more specific.

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't allow pre-filled messages. This is against developer policy. The user must manually fill out the message.